# Why does my AsyncCallback takes minutes? (C# using Compact Framework 3.5 on Win CE 5.0 Barcode Scanner)

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, compact-framework, windows-ce

a few days ago I started coding for a Barcode Scanner running on WinCE 5.0 in C# using Compact Framework 3.5. I had a hard time getting my asynchronous HttpWebRequest to do what it's supposed to. (especially because it's CF3.5..) Now it kind of works... But it takes 1-3 minutes until the Request is completed.

```
private void xmlRequestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri("http://www.mydomain.de/someFolder/index.php");
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType = "text/html";
    myRequest.SendChunked = true;

    myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), myRequest);
}

private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
    Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

    string postData = "testparam=testvalue";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
    postStream.Close();

    myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
}

private static void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

    Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
    string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(responseString);

    streamResponse.Close();
    streamRead.Close();

    response.Close();
    allDone.Set();
}
```

My Webservice logs everytime it is accessed. It just echoes "success". At first I thought the WebRequest doesn't work at all. But when I accidently didn't stop the debugging for some time I realized it worked but just took a very long time. The device even logged the answer "success" to the console.
So how can it be that it takes so long? Am I missing anything?

My goal is that the device scans some barcode and then contacts the webservice which gives back the product name and other information.

Comment: How is the device connected to the Internet (WiFi, Cell Data, etc.)?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot about that: It's connected via WiFi, full signal strength

Comment: Have you verified that the web service isn't the problem, by for example testing it with SoapUI, a small test program or something similar?

Comment: Maybe Webservice is the wrong word. I will connect it to some Webservice later. Now I'm sending the request to a PHP-file which logs the REQUEST Data. (Accessing via Browser + GET works including data. When the Scanner does the request, besides taking very long, there is no REQUEST data) Maybe there is a problem?

Comment: It could be a timout in the web request. I would lower the timeout value significantly and see if it returns quicker. Also try and verify that you can reach the php-file without problem from the device. For instance using a web browser on the device.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've set the timeout to 2, 3, 5 and finally 10 seconds. Everytime after that I get the timeout exception at this line `HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;` Maybe I should mention there is some third party WiFi configuration on the device. Can that be a problem? I will try to find a working browser!

Comment: Note: When I ping google.de on the device I get: "`PING transmit failed, error code 11010`" and directly after that I get the usual answer: "' Reply from 173.194.44.24: Echo size:32 time=21ms TTL=51`" (avg) I searched the web but didn't find any solution yet. I don't even know if these two issues are related...

Comment: I think I'm getting closer. The 3rd party software is this one: [SCU](http://www.summitdata.com/SCU.htm) My status page shows neither the AP Name nor the AP IP. Anyways the Scanner seems to get an IP at the upper edge of my DHCP range.. Any idea what i could try? Already tried WEP..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use this SCU client? Is there no suitable one pre-installed on this CE5 device (which model?)?

Is the server you use available thru the Internet or Intranet? Looks like you have a TCP/IP DNS or routing problem. Please try vxUtils (Cambridge Software - Free one) ping etc. to verify the connection.

You are aware off that your PC might be used by the device for it's Internet connection (ActiveSync/WMDC passthru).
Please try TCP/IP (and your app) without active ActiveSync/WMDC connection. You can still debug after first deploy/debug session start, as VS remembers the IP address of the device and uses it for following sessions, even if device is not connected to USB (WMDC). See also Visual Studio SmartDevice remote debugging.

If you con not find the network issue, come back with your detailed findings.